# Data not uploading to Firebase database (Android Studio)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've created very simple app on Android Studio and I want to connect to the Firebase. I've created a class:

```
public class Lek {

    public String nazwa;
    public String nazwa1;

    public Lek() {
    }

    public String getNazwa() {
        return nazwa;
    }

    public String getNazwa1() {
        return nazwa1;
    }

    public void setNazwa(String nazwa) {
        this.nazwa = nazwa;
    }

    public void setNazwa1(String nazwa1) {
        this.nazwa1 = nazwa1;
    }
}
```

And in my MainActivity I am trying to connect to Firebase database:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText e1, e2;
    Button b1;
    DatabaseReference reff;
    Lek lek;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        e1 = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        e2 = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        b1 = findViewById(R.id.button);
        lek = new Lek();


        reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("lek");
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                lek.setNazwa(e1.getText().toString().trim());
                lek.setNazwa(e2.getText().toString().trim());

                reff.push().setValue(lek);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I also created simple .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

But the problem is thet data is not correctly uploading on website. I set rules about writing and reading on true. In Android Studio I have connected correctly and set up dependencies corectly. When I try to upload data they don't appear on website. My google account is the same on website and in Android Studio. Can anybody had the same problem?

EDIT:
I've created Toast method on succes and fail, but it does show nothing on the screen:

```
 reff.child("lek1").setValue(lek)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            // Write was successful!
                            // ...
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            // Write failed
                            // ...
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: You're not checking for errors on the call to setValue() - something could be going wrong.

Comment: How can I check this?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#add_a_completion_callback

Comment: I've created a Toast on success and fail, but it does show nothing on the screen :(

Comment: Is one of those two Toast messages displayed?

Answer (score 0):

**Hi there, try this:**

1. First **Create Constructors** for nazwa and nazwa 1 variables in **Lek Class**

Where you create the new object :

```
lek = new Lek();
```

... take that line out and append the code **On Button Click** to not use the Class to upload data rather a HashMap like so:

```
HashMap<String, Object> lekHash = new Hashmap();
lekHash.put("lek1", e1.getText().toString().trim());
lekHash.put("lek2", e2.getText().toString().trim();
```

After this you can now set value on your reference like so:

```
reff.child("lek").setValue(lekHash).addOnCompleteListener(new OnComple...){
    if(task.isSuccessful){
        //Toast Whatever here
    }
}
```

Obviously all that "code" is not actually code, unfortunately, I didn't have my IDE but I hope you get the direction. And try and use more descriptive names for variables, which makes it easier to follow. Also, I recommend a concept called [delegation.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/delegation-vs-inheritance-java/#:%7E:text=Downcasting%20in%20Java-,Delegation%20vs%20Inheritance%20in%20Java,property%20of%20another%20other%20class.&text=Delegation%20means%20that%20you%20use,forward%20messages%20to%20the%20instance.)